# Android : NullpointerException in dbhelper.getreadabledatabase and getwritabledatabase

Tags: android

I am creating one app in which error is coming under this section of code : that is NullPointer Exception.. Please help me with this.

public class ThoughtsProvider extends ContentProvider {

```
private static final String AUTH = "com.bi.thoughts4u.ThoughtsProvider";
public static final Uri THOUGHTS_URI = Uri.parse("content://"+AUTH+"/"+DbHelper.TABLE_NAME);
final static int THOUGHTS = 1;

SQLiteDatabase db;
DbHelper dbHelper;

private final static UriMatcher uriMatcher;
static
{
uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
uriMatcher.addURI(AUTH, DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, THOUGHTS);
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri arg0, String arg1, String[] arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    if(uriMatcher.match(uri)==THOUGHTS)
    {
        db.insert(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }
    db.close();
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DbHelper dbhelper= new DbHelper(getContext());

    return true;
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
        String sortOrder) {
    Cursor cursor;
    dbHelper = new DbHelper(this.getContext());

    db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    cursor = db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);


    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return cursor;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri arg0, ContentValues arg1, String arg2, String[] arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

}

dbHelper class as follows :

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    static final String TAG = "DbHelper";
    static final String DB_NAME = "thoughts4u.db"; //
    static final int DB_VERSION = 1; //
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "thoughts"; //
    public static final String C_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    static final String C_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
    public static final String C_THOUGHTS = "thoughts";
    /*static final String C_TEXT = "txt";
    static final String C_USER = "user";*/
    Context context;

    public DbHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + " ( "+C_ID + " int primary key, " +C_THOUGHTS+ 
        "text," +C_CREATED_AT+ "text)";

        String sql1 = "create table thoughts ( id int primary key,  thoughts text, created_at text)";
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_NAME); // drops the old database
        Log.d(TAG, "onUpdated");
        onCreate(db);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
DbHelper dbhelper= new DbHelper(getContext());
```

in `onCreate` with

```
dbHelper = new DbHelper(getContext());
```

and remove the assignment (`dbHelper = new DbHelper(this.getContext());`) from `query`.

Comment: We tried your suggestions but it didn't worked. Getting same error at same point. Suggest if you have any other solutions.

Comment: @HerajMishra Post your stacktrace